# How to import a key into a MUSCLE card?

Tags: applet, smartcard, apdu

I am trying to import a key into the card, but it is giving response as `6F00` (UNKNOWN ERROR).The procedure i followed to import a key is

1. Load the (MUSCLE) applet
2. Initialize the applet
3. Verify the pin
4. create the object with id (`FF FF FF FE`):

> -> B0 5A 00 00 0E FF FF FF FE 00 00 00 44 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   <- 90 00

5. write into the object

> -> B0 54 00 00 8D FF FF FF FE 00 00 00 00 84 00 01 00 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   <- 90 00

6. Import key

> -> B0 32 04 00 07 00 00 FF FF 00 00 00 00
>   <- 6F 00

Please provide a solution for the above problem.

Comment: 7 bytes seems to be a bit low for importing a key. Before we have to read the full spec., what kind of key are you trying to import?

Comment: I am trying to import RSA public key of 128 bytes size, which is stored in the object FF FF FF FE in step (5).

Comment: Interesting, because I don't see any key...

Comment: I followed the guidelines provided in mcardport-1.2.1.pdf book for import a key into java card.According to this book first we need to create a object with id FF FF FF FE and write the key blob into this object then import key. In step (5) the command consist of not only a key it is a key blob.

Comment: That may be, but I would expect a key - or at least the modulus of an RSA key - to contain random looking bytes, not just a bunch of zero's. As Java Card's RSAPrivateKey can be quite picky, I would not expect it to accept this data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for the solution: 7 bytes seems to be a bit high for importing a key... ;)

The ACL in the data block is only six bytes, so this might cause your error. The following "optional parameters" are AFAIK completely unused.